# Cannot Match Any Routes Accessing a Controller – URL Segment Error

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I’m dealing with an odd behavior. I click on a button. The link is an absolute URL scripted as “/Auth/StartProcess”.  Auth is a C# Backend Controller. I’m using ASP.NET Core 5. For the frontend, I’m using Angular 13.  This works fine in my development environment. My web application works perfect running it on localhost.  However, when it’s deployed to a test environment, when I click on the button, I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ‘Auth/StartProcess”

If I just type the full URL like “https://localhost/auth/startprocess” works perfect. I don’t event need to click on the button to be able to get it to work.

StartProcess is the method that is inside the AuthController.  As you can see, this is not a component.
I don’t think I got an issue with my code related to the router, but I will share the code anyway. Like I said, this is working fine in my development environment.

**home.component.html**

```
<div>
         <a href=”/Auth/StartProcess” class=”btn btn-primary”>START</a>
</div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from ‘@angular/router’;
import { PagesComponent } from ‘./pages.component’;

const routes: Routes =
[
   {
        path: ‘home’,
        loadChildren: () =>
           import(‘./home/home.module’).then((m) => m.HomeModule),
   },

   {
        path: ‘Auth/StartProcess’,
        redirectTo: ‘/Auth/StartProcess’
        pathMatch: ‘full’,
   },

   {
        path: ‘ ’,
        redirectTo: ‘/home’
        pathMatch: ‘full’,
   },
];




@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**pages-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { Routes, RouterModule } from ‘@angular/router’;
import { PagesComponent } from ‘./pages.component’;

const routes: Routes =
[
   {
        path: ‘home’,
        loadChildren: () =>
           import(‘./home/home.module’).then((m) => m.HomeModule),
   },

   {
        path: ‘ Auth’,
        redirectTo: ‘/StartProcess’
        pathMatch: ‘full’,
   },

   {
        path: ‘ ’,
        redirectTo: ‘/home’
        pathMatch: ‘full’,
   },
];




@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Do you have a space here before AUTH ?  path: ‘     Auth’,

Comment: Hi Stefani, no. I just edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to leave spaces.   path: '',
This is well.  redirectTo: ‘/Auth/StartProcess’

Answer (score 0):

Assuming thet you want to redirect the /Auth/StartProcess to your PagesComponent

```js
const routes: Routes =
[
   {
        path: ‘Auth’,
        loadChildren: () =>
           import(‘./home/home.module’).then((m) => m.HomeModule),
   },

   {
        path: ‘’,
        redirectTo: ‘/Auth’
        pathMatch: ‘full’,
   },
];
```

```js
const routes: Routes =
[
   {
        path: ‘StartProcess’,
        component: PageComponent,
   },

];
```

Comment: Well, StartProcess is a method that start a third party UI. It's triggered by a C# Controller. Yes, after the authentication process is complete, it will be redirected to a page, which is a component. I will try your approach. Thx for your feedback.

Comment: Where should I put the second one?                                                                           
 const routes: Routes =
[
   {
        path: ‘StartProcess’,
        component: PageComponent,
   },

];

Comment: you posted two sections. So, the first one is for the pages.component.ts file? Is that correct?

Comment: If I create a routerLink button, I can reproduce the error in my development environment.  So, I scripted the button as <a routerLink="/Auth/StartProcess">Start</a>   As a result, I get the same error. Cannot match any routes. URL Segment 'Auth/StartProcess'    How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the above recommendation didn't work.

Comment: where do you want to redirect ?

Comment: If you want to auth make a login component. After that redirect to something else.

Comment: StartProcess is a method scripted as public async Task<ActionResult> StartProcess()    Then, the await command triggers a method related to a third party UI. Then, I need to redirect to a dashboard component.  The weird thing is that it works fine in my DEV environment.